# PgRouting Create network isn't splitting on intersections

Tags: pgrouting, splitting, network, road

I've started working with PgRouting, I have a custom road networks inside of a linestring geometry table.

I'm currently trying to create a Network for routing, the 70% of the routes are right, but sometimes I get errors. What I found was that when two linestrings intersects, it generates sometimes a node, but not always is splitting all the roads that are on the point.

This is what I've found:

[image]

On the picture you can look at the color bottom left road

On the map, the numbers that appear are the ID's of the differents part of linestring of the network splitted by the Create Network, but as you can see, the splitted road 316, still being 316 even after 3 differents nodes (nodes are the green circles). Why road 316 isn't being splitted more?

I've tried pgr_createnetwork('itineraries', 0.0) even with 0.0 tolerance is doing this. This way the splitted 316 can't reach the 705.

Comment: You are supposed to _increase_ the tolerance value to have it include non-overlapping vertices! Since this is a "*custom*" network, without exemplary data or a very thorough description it is hard to debug.

Comment: Thank you! Right now I've tried adding much tolerance to "create network", but now even adding this tolerance I still having some issues on route. I've seen that I have some roads with the some part of the segment that is the same as others. That can be generating an issue also for the routing?